# MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, html, mysql

MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order WHERE orderid='123'' at line 1

this is what I used

```
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order WHERE orderid='123'")or die('<span class="error_span"><u>MySQL error:</u> ' . htmlspecialchars(mysql_error()) . '</span>');
```

I don't see any mistake in the code, can someone please help me out?

Comment: It's telling you here `right syntax to use near 'order` - the operative word here being "order". Remember to read errors. See the duplicate it was closed with.

Comment: ORDER BY is a SQL keyword.  Choose another name for that table and you'll do better.

Comment: Or simply wrap `order` in backtips.

Comment: thank you duffymo for clarifying that.